# Injecting javascript to click on html button

Tags: javascript, swift

I am attempting to inject javascript into a WKWebView in order to add an item to my cart on a website.

I have a button:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to cart" class="button">
```

This is my code:

```
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('[value=\"add to cart\"]').click();") { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error: ", result)
        }
    }
//do something
```

I receive a nil error upon running this code. I have also tried inserting the type `submit` as a selector, which still resulted in nil. Is it possible that the DOM has not been loaded yet? I've attempted to fix this by adding a temporary sleep(3) before evaluating javascript, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could get it by Name and then add a click listener to it.

```
document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);

function myFunction() {
       //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. But you are calling a `click()` over the HTML element, before the element has the event listener attached. You should add an `eventListener` first, then call the click event.

Try this:

1. Add the event listener:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName(\"commit\"]')[0].addEventListener('click', event => { <YOUR CODE GOES HERE> });") { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error: ", result)
    }
}
```

Replace `<YOUR CODE GOES HERE>` with the actions that you want to execute when clicking, or replace the `event => {}` callback with the name of a previously defined function.

2. Call the click event:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('[name=\"commit\"]')[0].click()") { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error: ", result)
    }
}
```

Remember that `document.getElementsByName` returns an array of elements that match the query, hence the `[0]`. This could cause troubles if you have another input with then name *commit*

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    function testing() {
       //your code here
    }
</script>

<!-- add onclick to yours html button -->

<input type="button" value = "Test" onclick="testing();">
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I am not able to change the HTML structure of the button